# flasgger: reference marshmallow schema in a .py module

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flasgger

I have flask project with Marshmallow `Schema` classes defined in a `schemas` module.  For example:

```
project 
  - app.py
  - routes.py
  - schemas/
     - schema1.py
     - schema2.py
```

Where `schema1.py` is a typical marshmallow `Schema`.

```
class FooSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
```

The [flasgger](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger) docs show that schemas can be referenced in the docstring of a route.  Here's an abridged snippet

```
@app.route('/colors/<palette>/')
def colors(palette):
    """Example endpoint returning a list of colors by palette
    This is using docstrings for specifications.
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: palette
        in: path
        type: string
    definitions:
      Palette:
        type: object
        properties:
          palette_name:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Color'     <--------
    responses:
      200:
        description: A list of colors (may be filtered by palette)
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Palette'
        examples:
          rgb: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    """
```

The line of interest being `$ref: '#/definitions/Palette'`.  However, this is just an internal refrence to the `definition` section in the doc string.

Is there any way to just substitute a reference to the `schema/schema1.py` module instead?  In other words, **how can we drop in a schema reference to a module in the same project**?

Something like `$ref: 'schema/schema1.py#FooSchema'`...?  The [examples regarding marshmallow schemas](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger#using-marshmallow-schemas) are otherwise not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions should be handled in the template creating Swagger instance. For example in your case, you should define your swagger object in following manner:

```
from apispec.ext.marshmallow import MarshmallowPlugin
from apispec_webframeworks.flask import FlaskPlugin
from flasgger import APISpec, Swagger


plugins = [FlaskPlugin(), MarshmallowPlugin()]
spec = APISpec("My api docs", '1.0', "2.0", plugins=plugins)
template = spec.to_flasgger(app, definitions=[FooSchema])
swagger =  Swagger(app, template=template, parse=True)
```

After that you can use: `$ref: '#/definitions/Foo'` syntax in your definitions.

You may find this [snippet](https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/master/examples/apispec_example_uiversion3.py) helpful.

Comment: It will add definitions, but specs doesn't work any more and we can not have multiple api routes: https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/issues/483